# OpenGL - Properly updating the Vertex Buffer binding of a Vertex Array Object

Tags: c++, opengl, shader, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I have noticed a strange error in my program, which occurs when I bind a VAO multiple times after calling [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml). In my frame loop, I usually have one VAO for one draw call, but sometimes I would like to use the same VAO for multiple draw calls with different shaders. But this does not work in my implementation:

```
while(RUN){
    updateBuffers();//updates VAO
    drawThis();//binds and unbinds VAO
    drawThat();//binds and unbinds VAO -> OpenGL Invalid Operation error at draw call
}
```

Whereas this works:

```
while(RUN){
    updateBuffers();//updates VAO
    drawThis();//binds and unbinds VAO
    updateBuffers();//updates VAO
    drawThat();//binds and unbinds VAO -> works
}
```

Also this doesn´t work:

```
updateBuffers();
while(RUN){
    drawThis();//OpenGL Invalid Operation error in second frame
}
```

but this would work

```
updateBuffers();
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
while(RUN){
    drawThis();//only makes the draw call
}
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

... but that is not an option because I also want to use other VAOs in my frame loop (and I would like to stay flexible with the order).

So what are these functions doing internally?

The `draw` functions simply bind a VAO and a shader, make a draw call (usually `glDrawElementsInstanced`) and then unbind the shader and the VAO.

The `updateBuffers` function usually writes to a buffer object (initialized with `glNamedBufferStorage`) through a pointer which maps the entire buffer using the `GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT`, `GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT` and `GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT` flags. To ensure that I am not overwriting any data that is still being used by the GPU, I always write to a different partition of the buffer. So before each update I increase the write offset by the size of the previous update (or set it to 0 if the update would exceed the storage size).

And because the updated data should be visible to shaders, I have to update the binding points that the shaders bind to, too. I do this by calling [`glBindBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBufferRange.xhtml) for uniform buffers (used by uniform blocks) and [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) for vertex buffers (for vertex attributes) with each update, to make the binding offsets for each buffer start at the position of the updated data.

This always works fine for uniform buffer bindings (offset is updated with [`glBindBufferRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindBufferRange.xhtml)) but when I update the binding for a vertex buffer of a VAO (with [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml)) and then bind and unbind that VAO more than once before calling [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) again, I get an `Invalid Operation` error.

Why does [`glVertexArrayVertexBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindVertexBuffer.xhtml) cause a VAO to behave like this? What would be the proper approach to update the offset of a VAOs binding to a vertex buffer?